# Why is the generation of my TYPO3 documentation failing without a proper error?

Tags: typo3

I have a new laptop and I try to render the Changelogs of TYPO3 locally based on the steps on https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/docs-how-to-document/master/en-us/RenderingDocs/Quickstart.html#render-documenation-with-docker. It continues until the end but show some non-zero exit codes at the end.

```
project : 0.0.0 : Makedir
   makedir /ALL/Makedir
   2021-02-16 10:32:50 654198,  took: 173.34 seconds,  toolchain: RenderDocumentation
   REBUILD_NEEDED because of change,  age 448186.6 of 168.0 hours,  18674.4 of 7.0 days
   OK:
   ------------------------------------------------
   FINAL STATUS is: FAILURE (exitcode 255)
                    because HTML builder failed
   ------------------------------------------------
   exitcode:   0            39 ms
```

When I run the command in another documentation project, it renders just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue with this. It seemed the docker container did not have enough memory allocated. I changed the available memory from 2 Gb to 4 Gb in Docker Desktop and this issue is solved with that.